# Strange interaction between slider (input range) and combo box (select) when syncing them with jQuery and using up/down arrow keys

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox

I am working on a project where I needed to sync a slider value with a combo box value.  The code seemed to works.  But I observed something odd when I tried the two controls on Firefox.  I would move the slider and in the process, gain focus on the combobox.  Then I would use the up/down arrow keys on my keyboard and the selected item would move up/down as I'd expect.  But when I moved the slider a second time and repeated the use of the up/down arrow keys, the item selected by the slider was ignored in favor of the item previously selected by the keys.  I tried this on the current versions of all 5 major browsers and found this behavior on Firefox only.  So I removed as much extraneous code as possible to try to rule out an error on my part. [JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/crislawrence/84sfunLh/1/).

I reported the bug to Mozilla, thinking that I had identified a Firefox issue.  But the response I got back was that the problem I observed disappears when using plain old javascript.  I am using jQuery 3.3.1.  I tried plain old javascript and did see the problem vanish.  I also tried several earlier flavors (v2 and v1) of jQuery and got the above noted behavior every time.  I guess before I try reporting this issue to jQuery, I thought I might ask whether my existing code looks sound as javascript in general is not my strong suit. I am also wondering whether there is any way I can make this synchronization work without abandoning jQuery, which I do need for other purposes.

Here is the code below.  Note that while this code uses the range input as the slider, my initial code actually uses a jQuery UI slider.  It was with that widget that I first noticed the problem.  I reverted to the range input to eliminate jQuery UI as a possible culprit.

Assuming my code is sound and that there is a bug (jQuery or Firefox) can anyone suggest a possible workaround to avoid the behavior I am reporting?  Any and all advice is most welcome and appreciated.

Thanks, Cris

```
    <script>

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#coarse_slider").change(function() {
            $('#row_selector').val(this.value).trigger("focus");
        });

        $('#row_selector').change(function () {
            $("#coarse_slider").val(this.value);
        });

        $('#row_selector').val(8).trigger("change").trigger("focus");

    });

</script>

<div>
    <input id="coarse_slider" type="range" value="5" step="1" max="19" min="0" />
</div>
<div>
    <select size="20" name="row_selector" id="row_selector">
        <option value="1">A</option>
        <option value="2">B</option>
        <option value="3">C</option>
        <option value="4">D</option>
        <option value="5">E</option>
        <option value="6">F</option>
        <option value="7">G</option>
        <option value="8">H</option>
        <option value="9">I</option>
        <option value="10">J</option>
        <option value="11">K</option>
        <option value="12">L</option>
        <option value="13">M</option>
        <option value="14">N</option>
        <option value="15">O</option>
        <option value="16">P</option>
        <option value="17">Q</option>
        <option value="18">R</option>
        <option value="19">S</option>
        <option value="20">T</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change

```
<input id="coarse_slider" type="range" value="5" step="1" max="19" min="0" />
```

to

```
<input id="coarse_slider" type="range" step="0" max="19" min="0" />
```

and

```
<select size="20" name="row_selector" id="row_selector">
  <option value="1">A</option>
  <option value="2">B</option>
  <option value="3">C</option>
  <option value="4">D</option>
  <option value="5">E</option>
  <option value="6">F</option>
  <option value="7">G</option>
  <option value="8">H</option>
  <option value="9">I</option>
  <option value="10">J</option>
  <option value="11">K</option>
  <option value="12">L</option>
  <option value="13">M</option>
  <option value="14">N</option>
  <option value="15">O</option>
  <option value="16">P</option>
  <option value="17">Q</option>
  <option value="18">R</option>
  <option value="19">S</option>
  <option value="20">T</option>
</select>
```

to

```
<select size="20" name="row_selector" id="row_selector">
  <option value="0">A</option>
  <option value="1">B</option>
  <option value="2">C</option>
  <option value="3">D</option>
  <option value="4">E</option>
  <option value="5">F</option>
  <option value="6">G</option>
  <option value="7">H</option>
  <option value="8">I</option>
  <option value="9">J</option>
  <option value="10">K</option>
  <option value="11">L</option>
  <option value="12">M</option>
  <option value="13">N</option>
  <option value="14">O</option>
  <option value="15">P</option>
  <option value="16">Q</option>
  <option value="17">R</option>
  <option value="18">S</option>
  <option value="19">T</option>
</select>
```

and

```
$('#row_selector').val(8).trigger("change").trigger("focus");
```

to

```
$('#row_selector').val(7).trigger("change").trigger("focus");
```

in your jQuery.

See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xz6grtLw/).

Comment: Thx.  I was a bit sloppy.  But making the corrections you suggest doesn't seem to change the problematic behavior.  I tried your fiddle and saw the same problem on Firefox.  I am using Mac Mojave, if the platform makes any difference.